# Incorrect date being set with new Date()

Tags: javascript, date

When using the below line I am expecting the result to be '22/09/2017 14:05:43', however it is actually returning '09‎/‎10‎/‎2018‎ ‎14‎:‎05‎:‎43'.

```
var theDate = new Date('22/09/2017 14:05:43').toLocaleString();
```

I know there are js libraries out there such as moment.js that can be used for a lot of date time manipulation, but I was just wondering if anyone knew why this was happening and how I can get this to return the expected date?

Comment: JavaScript dates are in MM/DD/YYYY format, not DD/MM/YYYY format.

Comment: `Date` format should conform to standard supported by `Date.parse` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: When I try your code, I just get 'invalid date'. Surprised you don't.

Comment: It's either MM/DD/YYYY or the ISO's YYYY-MM-DD, as per https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp. I wonder why people insist on the MM/DD/YYYY when the ISO's YYYY-MM-DD is considered the international standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing of date strings is mostly implementation dependent, so it's generally recommended to avoid the built-in parser. Most browsers treat JavaScript dates with a pattern `xx/xx/xxxx` as `MM/DD/YYYY`, so `22/09/2017` is seen as either an invalid date (e.g. Safari, Firefox, Chrome), or the 9th day of the 22nd month of 2017 (apparently your browser).

Your browser is interpreting it as 'the 9th day of the 22nd month', so you're ending up on October 9th 2018, 22 months and 9 days into 2017.

To resolve this, you can separate the string into parts and give them to the constructor, avoiding the built-in parser (remembering to subtract 1 from the month number):

```
new Date(2017, 8, 22, ...)
```

Refer to [MDN's Date documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more information.

Comment: Not mentioning the ISO 8601 format while providing alternatives ("or separate your Date constructor [...]") could make people coming here from search engines believe that there is no other way. I believe the ISO deserves at least mentioning it in an answer that has been accepted. Also, https://xkcd.com/1179/

Comment: @RobG I've revised the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well the initial date `string` you passed to the `Date` constructor is wrong, it should be in the format `'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss'`.

Your actual code will give `Invalid Date`:

```js
var theDate = new Date('22/09/2017 14:05:43');
console.log(theDate);
var str = theDate.toLocaleString();
console.log(str);
```

Here `22` will be treated as a `month` and `09` will be treated as `day`. You need to fix it so it follows the **[`Date` standards](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/#Syntax)**:

```js
var theDate = new Date('09/22/2017 14:05:43');
console.log(theDate);
var str = theDate.toLocaleString();
console.log(str);
```

Comment: The issue is that the OP should not use the built-in parser for non-standard strings.